# how to register com components inside docker as regsvr32 command executes successfully but the com components are not getting registered?

Tags: .net, docker, com, regsvr32, dllregistration

We have deployed our .net application along with some COM components in docker but when we are trying to register COM dlls using regsvr32 the command gets executed without any error. But when we search for the CLS ID in the registry it is not available. But we are still getting Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed.

Its a 32 bit component. And 32bit is enabled in docker environment as well. We have tried with elevated access as well but no luck

Is it possible to register COM components in docker?

Comment: regsvr32 just instructs a COM component to register, it does nothing by itself. All registration work (registry change or anything else) is done by the COM component itself, so if regsvr32 works, the answer is yes, but ultimately what's changed depends on what's the component supposed to do. Also make sure you're looking at the good registry: 32-bit vs 64-bit also depending on the component

Comment: Are you running elevated in the container? If you want to successfully register, it needs to be run elevated. I am not sure if there is an error when running non-elevated or if it just registers for the currrent user...  Also, looking in the right place ? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432node\classes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After copying a dll named **msvbvm60.dll** into System folder inside container, dll registrations started working.

Comment: Worked.  More detail:  I copied this file from the host's c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ to the container in the same location and it worked for me.   (I noticed it is a hardlink to an uglier c:\Windows\WinSxS\... path.)

Comment: This solution did not work for me

Comment: @BNJ msvbvm60.dll is a dependency of DLLs compiled by Visual Basic 6. So the DLLs being registered by the OP of this question must have had it as a DLL reference. Your DLLs could have some different problem, maybe another reference is missing for example. But the point is that the issue was not really to do with docker per se.